# check all checkboxes that are not checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a column of dynamically created checkboxes. I have a check all checkbox at the top in the th. I need to check all the checkboxes Except the ones that are already checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" />
<input name=""rowBox type="checkbox" class="row checkbox" value="1" checked />
<input name=""rowBox type="checkbox" class="row checkbox" />
<input name=""rowBox type="checkbox" class="row checkbox" />

$('input.checkAll' ).on('click', function(){


$('input[name="name=""rowBox"]' ).prop('checked', this.checked)
  })
```

This works to check all the checkboxes, but it unchecks the ones that are checked on page load initially.

Comment: Why are you filtering out the checked checkboxes if you want them all checked? Also your HTML is malformed, with 'rowBox' floating by itself.

Comment: Sorry, typo on the rowBox. Tha is the name of each checkbox. I dont want the ones that are already checked, to get changed with the click event.

Comment: @jsNovice That is what he is asking. why you want to ignore it?? Does it cost you anything??

Comment: If I load the page with 10 checkboxes. 5 of which load already checked. The other five I want to change now to checked. If I check the check all button, they all get checked fine. What happenes when I make a mistake and dont want all of them checked. I click the check all again and they ALL get unchecked, right?

Comment: Yes; that's expected behaviour of the check/uncheck all button/checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

To archive your problem I used a `<button>`, generally I have an array which mark the checkboxes. "1" for checked and "0" for unchecked. Next I prove which is "1" and with `.prop()`I checked it again.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" />
<input name="rowBox" type="checkbox" class="row checkbox" value="ch0" checked />
<input name="rowBox" type="checkbox" value="ch1" class="row checkbox"/>
<input name="rowBox" type="checkbox" value="ch2" class="row checkbox" checked/>
<button id="revert">revert</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var sList = "";
$(".checkAll").change(function(){
    $('input[name=rowBox]').each(function () {
        var sThisVal = (this.checked ? "1" : "0");
        sList += (sList=="" ? sThisVal : sThisVal);
    });

    $('input[name="rowBox"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));      
});

$("#revert").click(function(){
    for(var i =0; i < sList.replace(",", "").length; i++){ 
      if(sList[i]=="1"){  
        $('input[value="ch'+i+'"]').prop("checked", true)
      }
      else{
        $('input[value="ch'+i+'"]').prop("checked", false)
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**Updated**

Check it out on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/hye7s8xz/4/)

Comment: Yes, this is the functionality I have currently. Again, if one or more checkboxes are already checked, I dont want to change the state of those.

Comment: ok I also recordnized that you didn't write the name of the input field in the double quotes.

Comment: Mario, yes that was a typo. I have proper html in my view.

Comment: @jsNovice I hope this will help you